# Toggle speed issue in FF and IE

Tags: jquery

```
$j('.sentence').toggle(
function(){ 
        $j(".tooltip:not(this)").hide();
        $j(".question-tt").show();
        $j(this).parent().find(".answer-tt").show();
        $j(this).parent().find("span").show();
        $j(this).parent().find(".show").show();
        $j(this).parent().find(".explanation").hide();
        $j(this).parent().find(".hide").hide();   
        $j(".sentence:not(this)").removeClass("current-2");
        $j(this).addClass("current-2"); 
},
function(){ 
        $j(this).removeClass("current-2");
        $j(this).parent().find(".answer-tt").hide();
});
```

I have many `.sentence` divs and when I click on one of them many times it toggles just fine, but when I click on the other ones constantly sometimes it doesn't get any clicks and after 1-2 seconds it will function again. 
This works great with Chrome but not in FF and IE. 
This is maybe because there are many actions in the toggle process but I need to keep them.
For live example: http://bit.ly/pG4Uma click on the first "Review this section" and then again first row, you see there are 4 rows that have the toggle actions on click, click on each after another and you can see the problem...

Comment: Actually it works great on my FF7, maybe you should specify a version.

Comment: Yes sorry, I use FF8 Beta version, but after testing the page on IE9 I thought there is a problem with the toggle action itself rather than the Beta version.

Answer (score 0):

You could optimize the function as below,

```
$j('.sentence').toggle(
function(){ 
        $j(".tooltip:not(this)").hide();
        $j(".question-tt").show();
        var parentElement = $j(this).parent();
        parentElement.find(".answer-tt").show();
        parentElement.find("span").show();
        parentElement.find(".show").show();
        parentElement.find(".explanation").hide();
        parentElement.find(".hide").hide();   
        $j(".sentence:not(this)").removeClass("current-2");
        $j(this).addClass("current-2"); 
},
function(){ 
        $j(this).removeClass("current-2");
        $j(this).parent().find(".answer-tt").hide();
});
```

similarly, you could just add a css style that hides an element instead of performing the below action,

```
parentElement.find(".show").show();
parentElement.find(".hide").hide();
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried both but still the problem remains... Are there any other ways to get this result without using `.toggle()` maybe?

Comment: you could achieve the entire effect using only css. That would speed things up. What i am suggesting is - have a parent css class that dictates the sytles of the child elements. So by just toggling the cssClass of the parent, the child node's style would toggle.

Comment: Actually there are other actions on the page that need this section to use jQuery. I've tried toggleClass instead of hide and show but didn't work. Any other solutions? Thanks.